# setTimeout can't access variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, settimeout

I'm taking a programming course where one of my projects is to create a Simon says game on Javascript, one of the functions i want to add is that the game each time a level begins it goes through each and every color of the sequence in order for the user to recall a bit better the sequence, for that i created this next level function:

```
function nextLevel(){
    //increasing level by one
    level++;

//Changing title to show level
$('h1').text('Level '+level);

    //Repeating the sequence (with the user sequence first as a test)

    var i;
    for(i=0; i <= userMemory.length; i++){
        var currentColor = userMemory[i];

        //Sequence walkthrough
            setTimeout(function(){
                makeSound(currentColor);
                $("#"+currentColor).addClass("pressed");
                $("#"+currentColor).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200);
                $("#"+currentColor).removeClass("pressed");
            }, 1000, currentColor);

    }
};
```

thing is that when i want to repeat the sequence i want to make it in order and kind of slow, because if i just do it like this:

```
for(i=0; i <= userMemory.length; i++){
            var currentColor = userMemory[i];
                    makeSound(currentColor);
                    $("#"+currentColor).addClass("pressed");
                    $("#"+currentColor).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200);
                    $("#"+currentColor).removeClass("pressed");
}
```

it will play all buttons inside the array all at once that's why i wanted to use a setTimeout function, but to my surprise when trying to do this it wont play nor apply the effects to the buttons and the console logs my error message as if the setTimeout function couldn't tell what the currentColor variable is, seems that it is out of scope (even though the variable it's inside the same function) am i doing something wrong? how can i pass the variable to the setTimeout?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: i'm not familiar with asynchronous JavaScript, i'm a newbie on this haha, is there any other way to simply "pause" the loop for a sec instead of using setTimeout?

Comment: oh, so you want each iteration 1 second apart ... that's three things you're doing wrong then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

asynchrony does that ... by the time the callback is called, for all instances, currentColor will be undefined, because it's assigned to the value of userMemory 1 greater than the number of items in that array (i.e. you have TWO issues with the code)

to explain the array issue ... let's say you have an array

```
let array = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

the indexes of the items are 0, 1 and 2

```
for (i=0; i <= array.length; i++) {
    console.log(array[i]);
}
```

will output, a, b, c and `undefined` - for when i == 3

Hope that's clear.

Also, based on a comment, it seems you also want each iteration to be 1 second after the previous one

you'll need to make each setTimeout 1 second longer than the previous one

modern browser fix -use `let`

```
// note, use < not <= ... an array of length 1 has 1 item, at index 0
for(let i=0; i < userMemory.length; i++){
    let currentColor = userMemory[i];

    //Sequence walkthrough
        setTimeout(function(){
            makeSound(currentColor);
            $("#"+currentColor).addClass("pressed");
            $("#"+currentColor).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200);
            $("#"+currentColor).removeClass("pressed");
        }, (i + 1) * 1000, currentColor);

}
```

other possible fix - use a function

```
function doThings(delay, currentColor) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            makeSound(currentColor);
            $("#"+currentColor).addClass("pressed");
            $("#"+currentColor).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200);
            $("#"+currentColor).removeClass("pressed");
        }, delay, currentColor);
}
for(i=0; i < userMemory.length; i++){
    doThings((i+1) * 1000, userMemory[i]);
}
```

Comment: I'm actually looking for the "simon says to repeat the sequence with a 1 second delay" i'm pushing all the buttons clicked to an array called userMemory before i do it randomized.
say, for example i click the buttons in an order so that the array i get in userMemory is: ["green", "green", "blue"]

i want that when i call the nextLevel(); function the computer will animate the green button, then wait 1 second, then animate the green button again and then the blue one (going through the same sequence i clicked, in order but with a delay)

Comment: I updated the answer to make each "makesound" etc one second after the previous before you even made that comment :p

Comment: gotcha, just one question, tried out the code and it worked perfectly, i just don't understand why you used (i+1) could you explain to me that part? :P

Comment: if i == 0, i * 1000 is zero ... zero delay ... you can use i * 1000 instead, it depends if you want that initial 1 second delay or not